# Including null values in an Spark Join [Scala]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dfs and I want to do an inner join on all columns

```
val seq1 = Seq((Some("1"), Some("Cat")), (Some("2"), Some("Dog")), (Some("3"), None))
val df1 = seq1.toDF("id", "name")

val s2 = Seq((Some("1"), Some("Cat")), (Some("2"), Some("Dog")), (Some("3"), None))
val df2 = s2.toDF("id", "name")

val s3 = Seq((Some("1"), Some("Cat")), (Some("2"), Some("Dog")), (Some("3"), None))
val df3 = s3.toDF("id", "name")
```

I want `df1.join(df2, df1.columns, "inner")` to result in df3, but right now it's excluding `("3", null)`.

I saw some answers using `<=>` or `.eqNullSafe` but I'm not sure how to apply this to scala code. I want a genera solution that can apply to any dfs - not knowing the names of columns in advance.

Can I do something like  `df1.join(df2, df1.columns.map(c => col(c).eqNullSafe()): _*, "inner")`? Compiler doesn't like it, but that's the idea.

Comment: so currently `f1.join(df2, df1.columns, "inner")` gives an empty dataframe. Whats wrong with `df1.join(df2, df1.columns, "left")` or `df1.union(df2)`? can you please add a more complete testcase?

Comment: My mistake! Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could build up your custom join-condition like this :

```
val joinCondition = df1.columns.foldLeft(lit(true))((acc,c) => acc and  (df1(c) === df2(c) or df1(c).isNull or df2(c).isNull))

df1.join(df2, joinCondition, "inner")
  .select(df1("*"))
```

But as your `df2` is empty in your testcase, this still results in a empty result. Can't you use `union` or simply a `left-join`?

Comment: `.select(df1("*"))` is a great trick! I was renaming the cols in df2 so that I could drop them without naming conflicts afterwards. Thank you!